# Your Organisations code coverage is 0% - When deploying to a seasoned Org

Tags: deployment, code-coverage, change-set

Anyone else seeing this? I am deploying to a seasoned org, with 87% coverage and all the errors relate to existing items.

When deploying even just a single item. Essentially every test fails with the same error, which all points to a single class. The class reportedly causing the error is already deployed and not in the new deployment.

[image]

The error for all tests is:

> line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: pkb_Controller:
>   line 12, column 16: Entity is not org-accessible Stack Trace: null

And the code snippit from that class is: 
[image]

And I found these in the Apex test results from an attempt to recompile: 
[image]

Comment: I have an org using the PKB product and found that I had to Disable Parallel Apex Testing - not sure if that is your answer but might be worth checking. Also does the running user does have the ability to create Knowledge Articles?

Comment: Also make sure that you license has not expired (or that it IS provisioned) for the org / user for that package

Comment: Thanks both for inputs, I have no exposure to PKB, but I did deploy successfully to this org 5 days ago, now it fails. I have added some test/compile results, it seems to point to a missing object KnowledgeArticleVersion. Is this possible?

Comment: Typically this error occurs when the user running the test does not have access to the package (License) or the package has expired. Is PKB a managed package or unmanaged?

Comment: Thanks Eric, I dont actually see it as an installed package at all, but all code is visible so assume unmanaged (and then uninstalled or never installed from package?) Still I am confused about the missing KnowledgeArticleVersion standard object

Comment: I had a similarly weird failure about a week ago.  SF complained my org had some ultra low test coverage percentage and a couple of triggers had 0 test coverage (which they didn't).  All I did was to re-deploy and the error went away...

Comment: @Eric, yes, think you got it here. It came down to a feature license issue. In the org the Knowledge base feature licenses had been removed. Which essentially had the effect of "deleting" the KnowledgeArticleVersion object (and other related stuff). We have code/tests that referenced this object that were rendered invalid... Thanks all for pointer, would have taken longer to get there otherwise. (if you want to formulate an answer, that I can accept?)

Comment: @dacology - Answer added

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an unmanaged package.

Comment: I found that tests had been modified in an unmanaged package to point to a licenced feature. That feature had been deactivated. Took a while to track it down. In this case knowledge licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you license has not expired (or that it IS provisioned) for the org / user for that package / knowledge base